# spring security can't find metadata file on classpath

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml

I finally got SAML SSO working on my application, which is serving as the SP. It's working with generated metadata, but I want to add predefined metadata for production.

I am trying to configure my ExtendedMetadataDelegate bean to see the xml file holding my SP metadata, but I can't figure out where to put the file so that spring will be able to see it.

The spring documentation says: "Store the metadata file as part of your project classpath, e.g. in WEB-INF/classes/metadata/localhost_sp.xml." I tried putting it in that exact location and it couldn't find it. I tried putting it in the same location as my keystore, which is under WEB-INF. It seems to be able to find the keystore just fine, but it can't find the metadata there either.

Interestingly , when I use the FilesystemMetadataProvider configured as below, my windows system can find the file, but my unix server and coworkers on macs can't. When the application starts up on a unix based system, this is the error message: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Metadata file '/WEB-INF/blah/filename.xml' does not exist
but the application continues on to run just fine and the SSO even works.

/WEB-INF/blah/filename.xml

when I use the ResourceBackedMetadataProvider configured as below, my system won't even compile because it can't find the file. The error is: nested exception is org.opensaml.util.resource.ResourceException: Classpath resource does not exist: filename.xml

I'm assuming that I need to change something on my classpath, but I don't know whether to change the build classpath or the run classpath. I tried adding WEB-INF to the run classpath and that didn't seem to help.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: The examples of your configuration didn't make it, can you add them to your question?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation does state: `Store the metadata file as part of your project classpath, e.g. in WEB-INF/classes/metadata/localhost_sp.xml.`

However, like you, I get classpath errors doing that. I've found that the application consistently picks this up, when I put it in: `src/main/resources/metadata/localhost_sp.xml`

Here is the error you get if you use WEB-INF/classes/metadata/...

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource#537c9fb7' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sec
urityContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource]
: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.opensaml.util.resource.ResourceException: Classpath resource does not exist: /metadata/localhost_sp.xml
```

For reference, here's the relevant portion of `WEB-INF/securityContext.xml` that is loading this metadata sp.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                        <constructor-arg value="/metadata/localhost_sp.xml"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
```

Overall, I find Spring Security SAML difficult to use/integrate/understand.

Comment: not that I can solve this, but please consider that there is IDP metadata and SP metadata.  As you would guess, ...sp.xml is for SP and idp.xml is for IDP.  The bean with ID "metadata" in SecurityContext file is for IDP not SP.  Please post your full SecurityContext XML file.

Answer (score 1):

They key is '/' in value:

```
<bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                        <constructor-arg value="/metadata/localhost_sp.xml"/>
                    </bean>
```